# How to create two-way Relation between two tables in Entity FrameWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, icollection

I have two tables that I want to create 1-n relation from `User` to `Contact` and reverse in EF. It means I need 2 way relation to 2 destination that they are base table too.
`Contact` table in user class should introduce as `ICollection` so my relation go wrong and both of them are one side.[check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10nRC.png) But if i remove `ICollection` every things is right.

How should I fix this problem?

```
  public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}       
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}        
    public Guid? ContactId {get;set;}
  }

  public class Contact
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    public Guid? UserId {get; set;}
  }
```

if i remove foreign key of contact [check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkVV4.png):

i want one more relation between these table but with different direction. [check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ucH.png)

Comment: Remove the `public Guid? ContactId {get;set;}` and `[ForeignKey("ContactId")]`. You want to 1-n relation for `User` to `Contact` so `Contact` should be defined as collection; i.e. `public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;} `

Comment: thank you...i tested as you wrote.. but i have one 1-n relation from "contact" to "user" . i need one more relation with reverse side direction too. from "user" to "contact"

Comment: Why do (you think) you need that extra relation? How would you use it?

Comment: let me say an example: my user table is for my boss and contact table is for his employees so every boss can have multi employees... so in contact table should insert user id that means who is your boss? then i want the name of one contacts that is for boss 1 that have another conditions too (for other tables that have relation with user table) so i should have contact id and virtual in my user table to take data from this. i hope that i explained clearly.

Comment: Again, how would you use it?  Use more C# (and maybe SQL) to calrify your problem.

Comment: network = context.NetworkActivities.Include(c => c.Document).AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(c => c.Document.User.Contacts)
                    .Where(c => c.Document.Plaque.Contains(plaque) && 
c.Document.CreatorId == userId) 
                    .Select(c => c)
                    .ToList();                                         i want contacts that has relation with user that has relation with document that has relation with network.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this. You can do this as follows

```
  public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
  }

  public class Contact
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
  }
```

**OR**

You can also try this way

```
  public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
  }

  public class Contact
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
  }
```

It includes foreign key property `UserId`

For more information, you can go to this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer.. i removed foreign key as you said but i have one 1-n relation from "contact" to "user" . i need one more relation with reverse side direction too.

Comment: In this solution, you have `ICollection<Contact> Contacts` navigational property from `User `and also `User User` navigational property from `Contact`. Doesn't it fulfill your requirements?

Comment: @MarzieKeshavarz Please see the modified answer.

Comment: no i need 2 relation but this code that you suggested create 1 relation i need 1 more with different direction

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class User
  {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}       
   // [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}        
   // public Guid? ContactId {get;set;}
  }
```

The 1-side of a 1-n relation doesn't have a foreign key.

Comment: thank you...i tested as you wrote.. but i have one 1-n relation from "contact" to "user" . i need one more relation with reverse side direction too. from "user" to "contact"

Comment: You already have Contacts, that's the n. When you also need a special Contact, ie HomeAddress then name it appropriately. Right now it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: some times i need to create 2 way relation... on other table it is OK and works but when i use "icollection" it is go wrong and create relation with opposite direction and if i remove "icollection" it will be right.

Comment: You are still not clear. In C# the relations are the navigation (virtual) properties and that is clearly a 2 way street here. What gets generated in SQL depends on 'conventions', there should be 2 primary keys and 1 foreign key in this model.

Comment: you are right they can communicate but in my DB if i don't create 2-side relation i can not rich some data ... this is because of some of my foreign keys that can be null and some that can't be null... i just need 2-side relation that one of them is icollection.. if i create this relation every things is well. can i have 2-side 1-n relation with icollection?

Comment: I see a 2 sided 1-n relation It's still not clear what the problem is. Edit your question and add some code that does not work like you wan it to.

Comment: i added 3 picture that can clear my question ... can you check them? i know i wrote code for 2 side relation but not works i think...

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 1-n relation from User to Contact you need an additional navigation property. To be sure about EF behaviour you can also configure the model.
This is an example.

```
[Table("User78")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual User MyPreferredUser { get; set; }
}

[Table("Contact78")]
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    { }
```

This is the context configuration

```
    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, true)
    { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(_ => _.Contacts)
            .WithOptional(_ => _.User)
            .Map(_ => _.MapKey("UserId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(_ => _.MyPreferredUser)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(_ => _.MapKey("ContactId"));
    }
}
```

in this example you cannot navigate from contact to user using the MyPreferredUser relation. If you need so you need to add a new navigation from contact to user (of type ICollection).

This is the DML generated by EF during migration

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Contact78] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [UserId] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [Contact78] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Contact78_a31c6496] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [User78] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [ContactId] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [User78] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_User78_a31c6496] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_UserId] ON [Contact78] ([UserId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_ContactId] ON [User78] ([ContactId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Contact78] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Contact78_User78_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [User78] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [User78] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_User78_User78_ContactId] FOREIGN KEY ([ContactId]) REFERENCES [User78] ([Id])
```